# Sort Laravel Nova partition results by the count

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-nova

I have a new Laravel Nova installation with a Property model. Properties have an attribute of 'country' and I want to show a partition metric on the 'country' col.

```
public function calculate(Request $request)
{
    return $this->count($request, Property::class, 'country','country');
}
```

All works, but it only sorts alphabetically by the country which rather than descending on the count which would make more sense.

Is there any way to sort the output?

Comment: show more code and output

Comment: There's nothing else to show. Everything else is standard Nova, which is great as it's very easy to set up, but I don't know how to sort the output. It comes out in country order. Australia (30 - 23.26%)
Belgique (1 - 0.78%)
Bulgaria (1 - 0.78%)
Canada (6 - 4.65%)
etc

Comment: try `return $this->count($request, Property::orderBy('country', 'desc'), 'country','country');`

Comment: That is helpful as I didn't know you could do that, but it reverse sorts the country names. What I want is to be able to sort on the counts descending so that the countries with the highest counts show up the top.

Comment: Sorry, I read too fast. I believe the request will add a `countries_count` to the select statement. So you should be able to do this : `return $this->count($request, Property::orderBy('countries_count', 'desc'), 'country','country');`

Comment: No, unfortunately. That makes sense but it returns: 'Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'countries_count' in 'oder clause' ...

Comment: In the source code : ```$results = $query->select(
            $groupBy, DB::raw("{$function}({$wrappedColumn}) as aggregate")
        )->groupBy($groupBy)->get();``` I guess it's named `aggregate` in nova. So replace `countries_count` with `aggregate` and it should work now

Comment: Brilliant! That's got it. Looks great. Please make that an answer so I can tick it. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you can do is :

```
public function calculate(Request $request)
{
    return $this->count($request, Property::orderBy('aggregate', 'desc'), 'country','country');
}
```

More information :
Nova will build the query as follow (*nova/src/Metrics/Partition.php@aggregate*):

```
 $results = $query->select(
            $groupBy, DB::raw("{$function}({$wrappedColumn}) as aggregate")
        )->groupBy($groupBy)->get();
```

- `$query` is the given Builder instance of your model `Property::orderBy(...)` or Nova will make it for you when you pass the model `Property::class`
- `$function` will be the method (count, min, max...)
- `$wrappedColumn` will be the given column (country in your case)
- `$groupBy` will be the given group by column (country) ...well you get it

At the end it will build :

```
$results = Property::orderBy('aggregate', 'desc')->select(
            'country', DB::raw("count(country) as aggregate")
        )->groupBy('country')->get();
```

Comment: How to add where clause to the above query? I want to add where('active', 1) to the below query
return $this->count($request, ContentLanguage::orderBy('aggregate', 'desc'), 'language_id', 'content_id')

Comment: Did you try `Property::orderBy('aggregate', 'desc')->select(
            'country', DB::raw("count(country) as aggregate")
        )->where('active', 1)->groupBy('country')->get();`?